# Fixing robot orientation using AR

Tags: python, opencv, orientation

I am creating a project where a robot needs to face a control panel and do some specific tasks. Some reference tags will be placed on the panel.

I want to use the tags as AR reference and fix my robot's orientation. But I am new in AR and I need to learn more, can you give me some hint on how to do this? I want to use OpenCV Python.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using april tags. They are similar to qr codes but were specifically designed with robotics in mind. There is a library on the april tag website. The library can be used to solve for the position and orientation of each april tag in a given image.

https://april.eecs.umich.edu/software/apriltag/